# In Google Play Can I Update Production Version When I have Higher Version On Beta Channel

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

On Google Play Console, I have told that "we can't upload a new bundle that lower than the existing ones". I get that because if version code is lower, users can't update their apps.

Recently we had a situation and we had to give a hot fix for production directly. So I updated version codes and prepared new release and gave hot fix. But I'm curious should I have done different ?

**What I Have Done ?**

1. Production was v1.10 , Closed beta latest release was v2.10
2. Production hotfix was v3.10 and overrides beta channels

Can I simply create a new release as v1.11 and update production in this situation ? I couldn't try it since it's company account and don't know the answer